# JavaScript problem in Basic Algorithm Scripting

Tags: javascript

The exarcise asks me to: "create a function that looks through an array (first argument) and returns the first element in the array that passes a truth test (second argument). If no element passes the test, return undefined.", and i wrote this code:

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
    let array = arr.map(func);

    if (array != null) {
        return array[0];
    }else {
        return [];
    }
}
```

Can anyone please explain to me why this is not working? For anyone who is wondering, this is the 9th exercise of Basic Algorithm Scripting in freeCodeCamp

Comment: Do not use higher-order functions like `map` here. Write a plain loop instead. It's an exercise in *basic* scripting.

Comment: First, check arr is an array, second, check function is match with Array.map and return items

Comment: "*why is this is not working?*" -  `array` will never be null, it will be an array of true/false values. It might at best be empty if `arr` was empty. And you should never return an empty array, the task says to `return undefined` if no element is found.

Comment: @VươngVũNguyễn Are you trying to describe why the current code does not work, or was that meant as a solution?

Comment: @Bergi sorry if my comment let you uncomfortable, i just try to get an advice but english not my native language and I have no sharing experience in stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

`array` is a new array containing the result of calling `func` on each element of the original array `arr`.

`array != null` will always be `true` because [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array, it doesn't return `null`. Therefore you will always end up on the `return array[0]` branch, which returns the first element of this new array instead of the first element of the original array where the condition passes, as the requirements state.

---

One way of solving your problem would be to loop through the original array (see the [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) statement for how to do that in modern JavaScript), call `func` on each element, and return the element for which the test passes (the element for which calling `func` on it results in `true`).

If nothing was returned by the end of the loop and your function ends up returning nothing, then that is equivalent to it returning `undefined`, so you don't need to do anything extra for that.

Solution:

```js
function findElement(arr, func) {
    for (const element of arr) {
        if (func(element)) {
            return element;
        }
    }
}
```

*(reveal after you completed your own implementation, or if you get stuck)*

---

Another way would be to use a functionality that already exists in JavaScript, which is the [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) function that's defined on all arrays and does exactly what you need. See [Michael Mishin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62169950/732284) about that.

And if you explore all the functions that exist on [arrays](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) (look at the left of the page for `Array.prototype...`), you'll find even more ways of doing this in JavaScript. Consider how you could use any of these functions to solve your problem:
[`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter),
[`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex),
[`forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach),
[`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Solution using your `map()` call and `indexOf()`:

```js
function findElement(arr, func) {
    // results is an array containing boolean values (true or false)
    // at the same positions (indexes) as the original values
    // from arr.
    const results = arr.map(func);

    // Try to find the index of the first passed test, which is the
    // first index where the test result is true.
    const firstSuccessIndex = results.indexOf(true);

    // indexOf() returns -1 if it can't find anything
    if (firstSuccessIndex > -1) {
        // If we're here, then indexOf() must have found something,
        // because firstSuccessIndex is greater than -1, so return
        // the element at the index found by indexOf().
        return arr[firstSuccessIndex];
    }

    // If we get here, then it means firstSuccessIndex was not greater
    // than -1, so indexOf() didn't find any passed test result (any
    // value in the results array that is true).

    // In that case, the requirements say that the function should
    // return undefined. Not returning anything is equivalent to
    // returning undefined, so we can end the function here.
}

// A shorter version of the same function could be:

function findElement(arr, func) {
    return arr[arr.map(func).indexOf(true)];
}

// If indexOf() returns -1, then the function will return
// arr[-1], and since there's nothing at index -1 in arr,
// arr[-1] will be undefined, therefore the function will
// return undefined.
```

*(reveal after you completed your own implementation, or if you get stuck)*

Answer (score 1):

`arr.map` returns the array of elements.
`arr.find` returns the first element found, and if there are no such elements, returns `undefined`.

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
    return arr.find(func);
}
```

Comment: Thought of that as well, but the post had some code in it and the question was "Can anyone please explain to me why this is not working?"

Comment: I explained: because Array.map always returns an array.

Comment: Yep, but that does not answer the question at least to the extend a lerner would get it. rid's answer far better.

Comment: If you think a little logically, then this is the answer.

Comment: @NiklasE. if you are dissatisfied about the answer, feel free to improve it by editing or post your own answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try to break your code down per line and read out loud what it is doing. This is a method called *rubber ducking* in which you explain to yourself what is happening (or pretending to talk to a rubber duck and explaining your code to it).

Your `findElement` function takes in two arguments, an array and a function. First you create a new array resulting from the [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method with the `func` as callback. The `map()` method will always return an array with the same amount of values as the original array. So unless your array was empty from the start, it will not get the result that you want. Instead use [`filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), [`find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`findIndex()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/findIndex) to get the a filtered array, a single item or an index to the item you are looking for.

Next you check if the array does not have a value of `null`. But based on the result of the `map()` method it will never be null. Instead you should check if the `length` property of the array is more than 0. This will indicate if the array is populated or not.

```
array.length > 0
```

Then if the array checks out you return the first item in the array. That is the correct approach.

In the else statement, when the array should be empty, you return an empty array. But the assignment asked to return `undefined`. Return that instead.
And if you only have an `if...else` statement and return something in both statements, then you don't need an `else` because the function will stop at either `return` statements.

So putting all the above together. With the `filter()` example.

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  let filtered = arr.filter(func);
  if (filtered.length > 0) {
    return filtered[0];
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

With the `find()` method.

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  return arr.find(func);
}
```

With the `findIndex()` method.

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  let index = arr.findIndex(func);
  if (index > -1) {
    return arr[index];
  }
  return undefined;
}
```

Or without any higher order functions and a basic `for` loop.
I would recommend learning the usage of these loops first before handling the array methods, because the internals of those methods work a lot like this. And knowing how it works will give you a greater understanding of what you can do with it and how to use it.

```
function findElement(arr, func) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    let current = arr[i];
    if (func(current) === true) {
      return current;
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}
```